# How to include "zero" in COUNT for combinations which don't exist in the table

Tags: sql, join, count, aggregate-functions

I have an Appointments table storing the date, the time of day (AM/PM), the building and the room -- for each of them:

```
create table appt (day char(10), tod char(2), bl char(2), rm char(3));
insert into appt values ('2016-01-28', 'AM', 'B1', '101');
insert into appt values ('2016-01-28', 'AM', 'B1', '303');
insert into appt values ('2016-01-28', 'PM', 'B2', '222');
insert into appt values ('2016-01-29', 'PM', 'B3', '456');
```

I need to output the count of appointments per date + time of day + building.

That's easy:

```
select day, appt.tod, appt.bl, count(*)
from appt
group by day, tod, bl
```

But I need to display all combinations, even the ones **where the count is null** -- and, there, I'm stuck.

Making use of `JOIN` does not help because it merely multiply the real appointments with the number of different times of day or the number of different buildings.

How could I solve this?  Giving me a hint to put me on the right path should be enough. Thanks!

See database and requests at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c055/2.

**EDITED--**

Target DB: MS SQL Server 2012.

I do have a table with all buildings. I do not have a table with 'AM' and 'PM'.

Expected result:

```
day         tod   bl cnt
----------   --   --  --
2016-01-28   AM   B1   2
2016-01-28   AM   B2   0
2016-01-28   AM   B3   0
2016-01-28   PM   B1   0
2016-01-28   PM   B2   1
2016-01-28   PM   B3   0
2016-01-29   AM   B1   0
2016-01-29   AM   B2   0
2016-01-29   AM   B3   0
2016-01-29   PM   B1   0
2016-01-29   PM   B2   0
2016-01-29   PM   B3   1
```

**EDITED 2016-06-09--**

I currently came up with the following code:

```
select refday.day, reftod.tod, refbl.bl, count(*)

-- Template.
from (select distinct day from appt) refday
cross join (select distinct tod from appt where tod in ('AM', 'PM')) reftod
cross join (select distinct bl from appt) refbl

-- Real data.
left join appt
on appt.day = refday.day
  and appt.tod = reftod.tod
  and appt.bl = refbl.bl

group by refday.day, reftod.tod, refbl.bl
order by refday.day, reftod.tod, refbl.bl
```

but the count is still not OK, returning 1 for days/tod where there is no appointment done:

```
day        tod  bl  cnt
----------  --  --  --
2016-01-28  AM  B1  2
2016-01-28  AM  B2  1
2016-01-28  AM  B3  1
2016-01-28  PM  B1  1
2016-01-28  PM  B2  1
2016-01-28  PM  B3  1
2016-01-29  AM  B1  1
2016-01-29  AM  B2  1
2016-01-29  AM  B3  1
2016-01-29  PM  B1  1
2016-01-29  PM  B2  1
2016-01-29  PM  B3  1
```

What am I missing?

Adding a `WHERE` clause to select the right records will remove them from the counts, but will bring me back to square 1: not all combinations are shown.

Comment: So what's the expected result? (With that input data.)

Comment: And what RDBMS are you using? Is time of day only AM and PM or are other values possible? Do you have a separate table with all the buildings?

Comment: Why, oh why are you storing dates as characters? Don't do that. Use a proper `date` column.

Comment: You'd need to add the source tables for bl and rm

Comment: I do use proper dates in real-life. Here, it was just for the example on SQL Fiddle. But thx anyway for mentioning it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL doesn't have the capability to give results for inputs that are not there.

Instead ***you*** need to ensure that those inputs exist.

*One* standard pattern for that is to create the desired output rows, left join your data to that 'template', then aggregate based on the template's columns.

```
SELECT
   DatesAndTimes.date,
   DatesAndTimes.tod,
   Buildings.bl,
   COUNT(appt.id)
FROM
   DatesAndTimes
CROSS JOIN
   Buildings
LEFT JOIN
   appt
       ON  appt.date = DatesAndTime.date
       AND appt.tod  = DatesAndTime.tod
       AND appt.bl   = Buildings.bl
       AND appt.rm   = Buildings.rm
WHERE
       DatesAndTimes.date >= '2016-01-28'
   AND DatesAndTimes.date <  '2016-02-01'
   AND Buildings.something = 'interesting'
GROUP BY
   DatesAndTimes.date,
   DatesAndTimes.tod,
   Buildings.bl
```

Cases like this are what makes having a 'calendar table' very useful.  And you should probably already have a 'buildings table' of some kind.

But it is equally acceptable to use sub-queries, common table expressions, or whatever you want, to create that initial 'template' on which to `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still can't get it returning the expected results. See new edition of the question with my current code.

Comment: Second point: is there a way to simplify the `select distinct tod` where I search for 'AM' or 'PM', and avoid taking 'FD' (full day)?

Comment: @user3341592 - Where you use `(select distinct day from appt) refday` to create your list of dates; if there are no records for a day, this still won't include that day.  You should create your own calendar table or number table.  Searching the web will show 1001 uses for such a table *(and 1001 ways to implement or populate such a table)*.  In short; don't use a sparsely populated table to create your templates.

Comment: @user3341592 - Where you use `(select distinct tod from appt where tod in ('AM', 'PM')) reftod` you could just use `(SELECT 'AM' AS tod UNION ALL SELECT 'PM' AS tod) reftod`  Or, even better, have that as part of your calendar table *(see my comment above)*.

Comment: @user3341592 - Where you're using `COUNT(*)` *(because I suggested it)*, you should be using `COUNT(appt.id)` or similar.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and precious advice. I should be able to finish my real request on my own, now.

Comment: Indeed, your last comment is important: we must `COUNT` something in particular, not `*`...